# Migration of a portal from web sphere (CMS) into OpenCms (CMS)

Tags: migration, websphere, websphere-portal, opencms

I would like to migrate a portal which is developed in WebSphere content management system into OpenCms (Content management system). To implement this I want to import the WebSphere template files into OpenCms, I have done R&D for it but I didn't find any solution. Can any one please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any provided solution for that. So you will either need to build your own migration tool, create it from scratch in opencms or stick with WebSphere Portal.